# How to create mutliple child windows from tkinter root window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and learning tkinter apps. I am trying to build an app that can spawn multiple instances of countdown timer and run them separately. I have been able to create a template code and can run one child window successfully but when I open another child window first one pauses and only the last one runs.

## MWE

**How to make all the child window countdown timers run separately?**
**Problem: If I click Scripts menu, then the countdown pauses itself.**

```py
%%writefile a.py
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox

def countdown(win):
    child = tk.Toplevel(win)
    child.geometry('400x300')
    child.resizable(0, 0)
    
    def _show_current_clock_time(label):
        str_clock_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
        label.config(text=str_clock_time)
        label.after(1000, lambda: _show_current_clock_time(label))
        
    def _countdown(child,v_hrs,v_mins,v_secs,int_secs):
        if int_secs is not None:
            total_seconds = int_secs
        else:
            total_seconds = int(v_hrs.get()) * 3600 + int(v_mins.get()) * 60 + int(v_secs.get())
        while total_seconds > -1:
            minute, second = (total_seconds // 60, total_seconds % 60)

            hour = 0
            if minute > 60:
                hour, minute = (minute // 60, minute % 60)

            v_secs.set(second);v_mins.set(minute);v_hrs.set(hour)
            child.update();time.sleep(1)

            if (total_seconds == 0):
                messagebox.showinfo('Times Up!')
                v_secs.set('00');v_mins.set('00');v_hrs.set('00')
            total_seconds -= 1

    tk.Label(child,text='Countdown Clock and Timer').pack()
    tk.Label(child, font='arial 15 bold', text='current time :').place(x=40, y=70)

    # label: current time body
    l_curr_time = tk.Label(child)
    l_curr_time.place(x=190, y=70)
    _show_current_clock_time(l_curr_time)

    # variables: secs mins hrs
    v_secs = tk.StringVar()
    e_secs = tk.Entry(child, textvariable=v_secs, width=2, font='arial 12')
    e_secs.place(x=250, y=155)
    v_secs.set('00')

    v_mins = tk.StringVar()
    e_mins = tk.Entry(child, textvariable=v_mins, width=2, font='arial 12')
    e_mins.place(x=225, y=155)
    v_mins.set('00')

    v_hrs = tk.StringVar()
    e_hrs = tk.Entry(child, textvariable=v_hrs, width=2, font='arial 12')
    e_hrs.place(x=200, y=155)
    v_hrs.set('00')

    # label: set the time
    tk.Label(child, font='arial 15 bold', text='set the time',bg='papaya whip').place(x=40, y=150)

    # button: start
    x,w = 0,40
    tk.Button(child,text='Run',bd='1',
           command= lambda x=[child,v_hrs,v_mins,v_secs,None]: _countdown(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4])).place(x=280, y=150)

    for i,minn in enumerate([1,2,3,4]):
        tk.Button(child,text=str(minn)+'m',
               command= lambda x=[child,v_hrs,v_mins,v_secs,minn*60]: _countdown(
                   x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]),).place(x=x+w*i, y=200)

win = tk.Tk()
menubar = tk.Menu(win)
menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Scripts", menu=menu)
menu.add_command(label='Countdown',command=lambda : countdown(win))
menu.add_command(label='Countdown 2',command=lambda : countdown(win))
menu.add_command(label='Countdown 3',command=lambda : countdown(win))
win.config(menu=menubar)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know the exact rules, but python tends to treat variables that are not basic types (int, float) as global variables. So when you set child a new value, even though it is in a function, you are overwriting the definition you had previously. So now you will only update the most recent child.

Comment: A better approach would probably be to make a class for the popup window. Then for each countdown timer create a new instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i am little behind on OOP and only familiar with functional approaches. But, I will try to learn that.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of problem that OOP is good at solving.

Comment: @BryanOakley Please illuminate me with some approach how to deal the question at hand!

Comment: Avoid using while loop in a tkinter application. Use `.after()` for `_countdown()`, like that used in `_show_current_clock_time()`.  Or use thread to run `_countdown()`.